# Using "C/C++ Makefile Project" extension on remote SSH server

Tags: vscode-extensions, vscode-remote

I am just starting to use this editor, and often use the "C/C++ Makefile Project" (Auth. Adriano Markovic) to run my programs (in C/C++ as well as Fortran). The way I do it is open a folder, go to the command pellet and select the option "C/C++ Make: INIT Project", which creates a nice directory structure that keeps source and object files separate, and places a Makefile at outside both these directory. It came rather handy on my local machine.

Now when I connect to a remote server from the VS code window, and install the same extension on said server, I can't manage to do the same; running the same option from command pellet has no effect at all - no directory or Makefile are created. Does any one know a fix to this, or do I have to look some other option (such as another extension or just copying the Makefile from my local machine to remote machine using SCP along with creating the directories manually so that I don't have to modify the Makefile)?

Edit: This extension has neither the source code openly available nor is actively maintained. Thus I am seeking suggestions for some other extensions that more or less does the same thing as I described.

Comment: Most VSCode extensions have been updated by their authors so as to be compatible to VSCode Remote development. However, the one you used was not updated since 2019 and its author did not make the source code available like others. So you probably should assume it is a dead project right now and time to explore alternatives.

Comment: Ok, I will do that. Do you have any suggestions that more or less does the same thing as I described? Thank you.